# Ant: How to echo a path when it contains a refid?

Tags: java, ant

Please see this ant snippet below --

```
<path id="classpath.ejb">
    <path refid="${java.class.path}"/>
    <pathelement location="${my.id}_session_${version.suffix}.jar"/>
</path>
```

Here I want to see the content of `classpath.ejb`, the fact is that it is composed of two elements, one is the generic system `$CLASSPATH` (supplied as a `refid`) and the second one is some another jar. Just for my curiosity, I want to make sure the contents of `classpath.ejb` looks fine. But when I try to echo like --

```
<echo message="java.class.path: ${java.class.path}"/>
<echo message="classpath.ejb: ${toString:classpath.ejb}"/>
```

The first echo works, but in the second line, ant says that --

```
BUILD FAILD
build.xml:103:Reference <...my whole $CLASSPATH string...> not found.
```

Any idea ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `<path>` is faulty.  In this line:

```
<path refid="${java.class.path}"/>
```

You are saying the value of `${java.class.path}` is a reference, but it's not, it is a 'string' path.  Hence your error about a missing reference.  You could change it to, for example,

```
<path path="${java.class.path}"/>
```

So that the `classpath.ejb` path is composed from the Java classpath and your 'session' jar.
Or else, see *[Path-like Structures](http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#path)* in the Ant docs.